# Using Hyper-parameters from H2O to re-build XGBoost in Sklearn gives Difference Performance in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, h2o, xgboost

After using H2O Python Module AutoML, it is found that XGBoost is on the top of the Leaderboard. Then what I was trying to do is to extract the hyper-parameters from the H2O XGBoost and **replicate** it in the XGBoost Sklearn API. However, the performance is different between these 2 approaches:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

import xgboost as xgb
import scikitplot as skplt
import h2o
from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

h2o.init()


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

data = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([X, y[:,None]], axis=1)) 
data.columns = iris.feature_names + ['target']
data = data.sample(frac=1)
# data.shape

train_df = data[:120]
test_df = data[120:]

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into H2O
train = h2o.H2OFrame(train_df)
test = h2o.H2OFrame(test_df)

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "target"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()
test[y] = test[y].asfactor()

aml = H2OAutoML(max_models=10, seed=1, nfolds = 3,
                keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
                exclude_algos = ["GLM", "DeepLearning", "DRF", "GBM"])
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)
# View the AutoML Leaderboard
lb = aml.leaderboard
lb.head(rows=lb.nrows)

model_ids = list(aml.leaderboard['model_id'].as_data_frame().iloc[:,0])
m = h2o.get_model([mid for mid in model_ids if "XGBoost" in mid][0])
# m.params.keys()
```

1. Performance of H2O Xgboost

```py
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(test_df['target'], 
                                    m.predict(test).as_data_frame()['predict'], 
                                    normalize=False)
```

[image]

2. Replicate in XGBoost Sklearn API:

```py
mapping_dict = {
        "booster": "booster",
        "colsample_bylevel": "col_sample_rate",
        "colsample_bytree": "col_sample_rate_per_tree",
        "gamma": "min_split_improvement",
        "learning_rate": "learn_rate",
        "max_delta_step": "max_delta_step",
        "max_depth": "max_depth",
        "min_child_weight": "min_rows",
        "n_estimators": "ntrees",
        "nthread": "nthread",
        "reg_alpha": "reg_alpha",
        "reg_lambda": "reg_lambda",
        "subsample": "sample_rate",
        "seed": "seed",

        # "max_delta_step": "score_tree_interval",
        #  'missing': None,
        #  'objective': 'binary:logistic',
        #  'scale_pos_weight': 1,
        #  'silent': 1,
        #  'base_score': 0.5,
}

parameter_from_water = {}
for item in mapping_dict.items():
    parameter_from_water[item[0]] = m.params[item[1]]['actual']
# parameter_from_water

xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(**parameter_from_water)
xgb_clf.fit(train_df.drop('target', axis=1), train_df['target'])
```

3. Performance of Sklearn XGBoost:
   **(always worse than H2O in all examples I tried.)**

```py
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(test_df['target'], 
                                    xgb_clf.predict(test_df.drop('target', axis=1)  ), 
                                    normalize=False);
```

[image]

Anything obvious that I missed?

Comment: I tried your code and every time I get the same result. Have you modified your `train_df` and `test_df` after training H2O and before XGBoost?

Answer (score 6):

When you use H2O auto ml with the following lines of code :

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_models=10, seed=1, nfolds = 3,
                keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
                exclude_algos = ["GLM", "DeepLearning", "DRF", "GBM"])
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)
```

you use the option `nfolds = 3`, which means each algorithm will be trained three times using 2 thirds of the data as training and one third as validation. This allows the algorithm to be more stable and sometimes have better performance than if you only give your entire training dataset in one go.

This is what you do when you train your XGBoost using `fit()`. Even though you have the **same** algorithm (XGBoost) with the **same** hyperparameters, you don't use the training set the same way H2O does. Hence the difference in your confusion matrices !

If you want to have the same performance when copying the best model, you can change the parameter `H2OAutoML(..., nfolds = 0)`

---

Furthermore there H2O's takes into account approximately 60 different parameters, you missed a few important ones in your dictionary like the `min_child_weight`. So your xgboost is not exactly the same as your H2O which could explain the differences in performance

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out the difference in training steps. Even though after changing to `H2OAutoML(..., nfolds = 0)`, there are still minor performance differences. More importantly, however, is how to get the training steps of sklearn-xgboost be similar to H2O's, rather than *downgrade* H2O's to be like sklearn's. To achieve this, would calling `xgb_clf.fit(train_df.drop('target', axis=1), train_df['target'])` three times be sufficient?

Comment: Fitting three times wouldn't work since you divide your training set in three when you use k-fold operations. So you would have to get the exact same three folds that H2O made. You could try the option `keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = True` to keep them.

Comment: And did you try to transfer all the features of your H2O xgboost model @B.Sun ? You only transfered 10 in your example

Comment: Would you mind to be more specific on "transfer features"? Do you mean 'asfactor'?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I meant fixing all the parameters in the XGBoost to be the same as in your h2o model. You did it for some parameters but not for all. For example your didn't fix the `min_child_weight` parameter in your XGBoost model to be the same as your h2o model

Comment: @B.Sun have you ever try vlemaistre 's advice to mapping all parameters from h2o to sklearn?